# Function to find if any char as int is > 127

Tags: haskell, character

I have following simple code to find if any character of string converted to int is > 127 :

```
isbinary ss = do
    if any (>127) ss 
    then return "True"
    else return "False"

mystr = "this is a test"
main = do 
    print (isbinary mystr)
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ runghc isbinary.hs

isbinary.hs:9:9: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show (m0 [Char]))’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘m0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 14 others
        ...plus 24 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (isbinary mystr)
      In the expression: do { print (isbinary mystr) }
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { print (isbinary mystr) }

isbinary.hs:9:16: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of ‘isbinary’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(isbinary mystr)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (isbinary mystr)
      In the expression: do { print (isbinary mystr) }
```

`print $ isbinary mystr` also does not work.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Comment: (1) `isBinary` doesn't need a do-block, because you aren't using `IO` or any other monad there. (2) Adding type signatures to your top-level definitions would have resulted in a clearer error message. (3) `any (>127) ss` is trying to use a test for numbers (`(>127)`) on characters (the elements of `ss`). You need to convert the characters to numbers before doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Char` is not a numeric type (unlike in a language like C) - this is what the `No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of ‘isbinary'` is trying to tell you. You need to explicitly convert it. Let's search - I typed `Char -> Int` into [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Char%20-%3E%20Int). The second result [`ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:ord) is what we're looking for.

```
import Data.Char (ord)

isbinary :: String -> Bool
isbinary s = any (\c -> ord c > 127) s
```

To make the intent clearer, it you could use the [isAscii](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isAscii) function

```
import Data.Char (isAscii)

isbinary :: String -> Bool
isbinary s = any (\c -> not (isAscii c)) s
```

Cleaning up the code a little bit (we usually eta-reduce and use camelCase names)

```
import Data.Char (isAscii)

isBinary :: String -> Bool
isBinary = any (not . isAscii)
```

One more possible solution is to write `isBinary = any (> '\127')`.

Comment: Very well explained. Can we use `charToInt` ?  ( https://hackage.haskell.org/package/basement-0.0.10/docs/Basement-IntegralConv.html#v:charToInt )

Comment: @rnso You probably wouldn't want to because that function is in a separate package, and would require a dependency.